# Fopen - No such file or directory in C

Tags: c

This code does not open file properly, it returns no such file or directory, although the path and privilege are there and no other program is using the file. How can I fix the error? I tried swapping the path and moving the file, the error is there still.

```
    char string[105];
    FILE* file = fopen("C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\a.txt", "r");
    while (fgets(string, 100, file)) {
        printf("%s", string);
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear, from what you've shown, how you'd know whether or not it opens the files properly; you're not checking `file`.

Comment: It also depends on what shell you’re using. Are you using a posix emulation shell like msys2?

Comment: @xev Where is the shell involved here?

Comment: Using an msys2 shell to compile C code, you’d have to pass the path as "/c/Users/Public/Documents/a.txt"

Comment: @xev Isn't that due to the compiler itself rather than the shell that launched this compiler?

Comment: It depends on the system. A compiler running on posix emulation depends on posix paths. You can try with clang run on msys2 then on the native command prompt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be surprisingly tricky to open a simple file!  Lots of things can go wrong.  I recommend writing slightly more verbose code, like this:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

char* filename = "C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\a.txt";
char string[105];
FILE* file = fopen(filename, "r");
if (file == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "can't open %s: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}
while (fgets(string, 100, file)) {
    printf("%s", string);
}
```

The point is that the error message prints out both the name of the file it tried but failed to open, and the actual reason it couldn't open it.  (Also, by storing the filename in a variable, you make it absolutely certain that the filename it prints in the error message is the filename it tried but failed to open.) It sounds like you already know that the error was "no such file or directory", but I'm not sure how you know this.

Even though I've been programming in C for a long time, sometimes I still have this problem.  One thing I'll sometimes do is use my mouse to copy the *exact* filename string printed in the error message, the file the program said it couldn't open, the file I'm sure is really there, and paste it into a terminal window (or CMD or Powershell if you're on Windows), along with a directory-listing command, to see if the operating system can actually see the file.  That is, for your example, the command I'd run is

```
dir C:\Users\Public\Documents\a.txt
```

but the point is that I would not actually type the pathname "`C:\Users\Public\Documents\a.txt`", instead I would copy and paste it out of the error message that the program printed.  Sometimes there are surprising little impossible-to-spot differences between the filename you thought it was trying to open, versus the filename it was *actually* trying to open, and this exercise is a good way to let the computer help you find those differences.

Remember, too, that you'll get the error "No such file or directory" if there's no file by that name in the directory, *or* if the directory isn't there at all.  For example, if you're trying to open the path

```
C:\Users\Public\Documents\a.txt
```

and the file `a.txt` keeps not being there, and you keep checking your home directory

```
C:\Users\Donkey\Documents
```

and you keep seeing that the file *is* there, it can be surprisingly easy to overlook what the real problem is. :-)

---

Addendum: You *might* be having an issue with the different Unix/Linux versus Windows file path separators, that is, `/` versus `\`.  Usually, on a Windows machine, it's safest to use `\`, as you've done.  (One very frequent mistake is to forget to double the backslashes, but it looks like you got that right.)  Depending on your programming environment, if there's some level of Unix emulation going on, you can sometimes use Unix-style `/`, and it will automatically translate to `\` for you.  I've never heard of a situation where using `\` made it *not* work (which is a possibility being explored in the comments), but you might experiment with that, perhaps trying

```
char* filename = "/c/Users/Public/Documents/a.txt";
```

or (less likely)

```
char* filename = "C:/Users/Public/Documents/a.txt";
```

Comment: I used errno to check the error, but just thought it wasn't necessary to post it here. When I used fopen with "w" to create the file it started to work randomly when I try to read it... Dunno what was the problem, either way it solved the issue when moving files, etc. I'll experiment with your answer, but right now I believe the issue is solved (at least on this one project). :) Thanks!

Comment: For me, nothing else worked with MSYS2 except prepending `c:/msys64` to the pathname. So, for example, `/usr/share/my-prog/datafile.dat` became `c:/msys64/usr/share/my-prog/datafile.dat`. Then the program could `fopen` the file, regardless if it was launched from mintty or from Windows itself.