# Why is the file not opening using fopen?

Tags: c, file

I have tried several methods but none of them have worked.
I copied the txt file into the root file and it didn't open too. I have also tried to use the full path of the txt file. The same thing happened when I tried to use another IDE on another laptop.
Also the compiler isn't giving me any error.

Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
    struct TreeNode *tmpDicNode;
    struct LinkedList *tmpLinkedList;

    FILE *infile;
    infile = fopen("..//Synonyms.txt" ,"r");
    char line[500];

    while(fgets(line, 500, infile))
    {
        //if ( strlen(line)>0){
            line[strlen(line) - 2] = '\0';

        char * token = strtok(line, " -\n");
        tmpDicNode = newTreeNode(token);
        tmpLinkedList = newLinkedList();

        while(token != NULL )
        {
            token = strtok(NULL, " , -\n");
            if (token != NULL)
            {
                insertSynonym(tmpLinkedList, token);
            }
        }
        tmpDicNode->synonyms = tmpLinkedList;
        Root = insertWord(Root, tmpDicNode);
    }

    fclose(infile);

    int ch = 0;
    char userWord[30];
    char userWord2[30];
    while(ch!=8)
    {
        printf("\n=====================================\n");
        printf("1. View The Dictionary.\n");
        printf("2. test word existence.\n3. print synonyms of a word.\n");
        printf("4. add a synonym to a word.\n5. get the biggest word with synonyms.\n");
        printf("6. get all words of a synonym.\n");
        printf("7. Save the dictionary to dict.txt file.\n");
        printf("8. Exit.\n");
        printf("=====================================\n");
        printf("\nEnter Your Choice: ");
        scanf("%d",&ch);
        switch (ch)
        {
        case 1:
            viewDictionary(Root);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Enter word: ");
            scanf("%s", userWord);
            if (findWordNode(userWord)) printf("%s is present in the dict \n", userWord);
            else printf("%s isn't found! \n", userWord);
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Enter word: ");
            scanf("%s", userWord);
            printLinkedlist(findWordNode(userWord)->synonyms);
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("Enter word: ");
            scanf("%s", userWord);
            printf("Enter synonym: ");
            scanf("%s", userWord2);

            AddToWordSynonyms(userWord, userWord2);
            break;
        case 5:
            printf("The word with the height no. of Synonyms is: %s", getMaxSynsWord(Root)->word);
            break;
        case 6:
            printf("Enter a synonym: ");
            scanf("%s", userWord);
            getSyncWords(Root, userWord);
            break;
        case 7:
            saveTheDictToFile(Root);
            printf("The dictionary saved to others/dict.txt, Go and check it!\nGoodbye..!\n");
            ch = 8;
            break;
        case 8:
            printf("Goodbye..!\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("Please Enter a valid option number from 1 to 7\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You should check `errno` whenever `fopen` returns `NULL`. (Btw, did you by any chance put an extra `/` in `"..//Synonyms.txt"`?)

Comment: @Rinad Akl - mediocrevegetable is correct.  1) You should ALWAYS check if `infile = fopen()` returns 0.  This indicates "fopen failed".  2) Check [errno](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) or call [perror()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) to find out WHY it failed.  3) `"..//Synonyms.txt"` is almost certainly WRONG.  You probably meant `"..\\Synonyms.txt"`.

Comment: Always check the return value of `fopen`.  Otherwise you have no idea if the open succeeded or not.  Also the following is unsafe:  `line[strlen(line) - 2] = '\0';`  What do you think will happen if `strlen` returns `0` or `1`?  This will also discard useful characters if you ever read a long line, or a line that doesn't end in a CRLF sequence.

Comment: If that is Windows filing system, the double (escaped) slash is sloped the wrong way.

Comment: Please note that ".." is relative to the current directory of the process (shell or IDE) running the program, and is unrelated to the directory where the program resides.

Comment: One way to find out, is to *create* a file with an unusual name at the same location, and then look for where it is.

Comment: I checked if the file is NULL in the functions not in the main. Iam still getting File not found. I changed the slashes and path but nothing worked

Comment: Can you tell what platform you're using and show the relevant directories?

Comment: I am using Code Blocks.

Comment: There is also a problem that whenever I provide the full path "C:\\...." I get no output at all in the compiler not even the options from the switch.

Comment: By platform I meant Windows or Linux or whatever, it'll make it clear what separator you're trying to use. And the directories can help provide the correct relative/absolute file path.

Comment: Actually, by that `C:` I just saw, it seems like you're using windows. If changing `//` to `\\\` still doesn't work, please provide the directories.

Comment: I am using Windows.

Comment: C:/Users/CLICK ONCE/Desktop/Semester 4/i2206/Project/Synonyms.txt  These are the directories. This path actually worked in another code.

Comment: And the executable is in `C:/Users/CLICK ONCE/Desktop/Semester 4/i2206/Project/some_dir/` (where some_dir is just some folder in `Project`?

Comment: the executable file and the txt file were in separate folders. I tried to put them together; it didn't work either. I don't know why whenever I provide the whole path the whole code stops. I just get a black page with no output at all.

Comment: Take a look at [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67943970/fopen-no-such-file-or-directory-in-c) for some additional hints.

Answer (score 0):

Let's address a couple of the issues here:

**synonyms.txt**

```
cold: cool,frigid,freezing
good: acceptable,virtuous
```

**readsyn.c**

```
/*
 * readsyn.c
 *
 * SAMPLE OUTPUT:
 *   Current directory: C:\Users\paulsm\workspace-cdt\readsyn\Debug
 *   Opening file (..\synonyms.txt)
 *   Reading file (..\synonyms.txt)
 *   line=cold: cool,frigid,freezing
 *   ...
 *   Currently 4 words
 *   line=good: acceptable,virtuous...
 *   Currently 7 words
 *   Done: found 2 lines
 *   synonyms[0]:cold synonyms[1]:cool synonyms[2]:frigid synonyms[3]:freezing synonyms[4]:good synonyms[5]:acceptable synonyms[6]:virtuous
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAXWORDS 10
#define MAXLINE 80
#define TOKENS ":,"
#define FNAME "..\\synonyms.txt"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char synonyms[MAXWORDS][MAXLINE] = {0};
    char current_folder[MAXLINE];
    char line[MAXLINE], *token;
    FILE *infile;
    int nlines = 0, iword=0;

    printf ("Current directory: %s\n", getcwd(current_folder, MAXLINE));

    printf ("Opening file (%s)\n", FNAME);
    if (!(infile = fopen(FNAME,"r"))) {
        perror("File open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("Reading file (%s)\n", FNAME);
    while((fgets(line, MAXLINE, infile) != NULL) && (iword < MAXWORDS))
    {
        printf("line=%s...\n", line);
        if (line[strlen(line)-1] == '\n')
            line[strlen(line)-1] = 0;
        token = strtok(line, TOKENS);
        while (token != NULL) {
            strncpy (synonyms[iword], token, MAXLINE);
            token = strtok(NULL, TOKENS);
            iword++;
        }
        printf("Currently %d words\n", iword);
        nlines++;
    }

    fclose(infile);
    printf ("Done: found %d lines\n", nlines);
    for (int i=0; i < iword; i++)
        printf ("synonyms[%d]:%s ", i, synonyms[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Main points:

- ALWAYS check if an I/O operation like "fopen()" succeeded or failed.
- You can use APIs like [getcwd()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getcwd.3.html) (among others) to get your current working directory.
- If — as in your example — you don't give an absolute path (like "C:\\temp\\f.txt" on Windows, or "/tmp/f.txt" on *nix) for your filename, then the path argument is interpreted relative to that *current working directory* of the application. In Visual Studio that is by default somewhere buried in the Debug directory of your project; in Linux it would be the current directory of your shell.

Comment: I edited the last part about absolute vs. relative paths a bit to make it crystal clear (I hope); feel free to roll back if you don't like it.

Comment: @Peter - thank you :)  I was tempted to add a) APIs like fopen() accept *EITHER* -nix-style forward slashes ("/") *AS WELL AS* DOS/Windows back slashes ("\"), and b) the problem with back-slashes is that they're both an [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) *AND* [path delimiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing))... but that would have been "a bit much" ;)

Comment: @Rinad Akl - are you squared away?

Comment: @paulm What do you mean with that? I had to look the expression up (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/squared%20away) but cannot apply one of the meanings to this context ;-).